# Как узнать какая переменная создалась позже другой?

Tags: php

```html
if(isset($catalog_filter_array['category'])) {
    $category_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['category'], 'girls');
    $term = $category_term;

}
if(isset($catalog_filter_array['service'])) {
    $service_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['service'], 'services');

    $term = $service_term;
}
if(isset($catalog_filter_array['city'])) {
    $city_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['city'], 'city');

    $term = $city_term;
}
```

примерно такой код. Должна быть только 1 переменная term если все 3 условия будут верны то будет только последний $term но не факт что он был создан последним. Есть способ проверить какая перемена была создана позже всех?

Comment: Переменная `$term` в любом случае одна, потому как вы только изменяете ее значения. "но не факт что он был создан последним" - по какой логике определяется "последний"?

Comment: Тут вопрос в том,как у вас создается `$catalog_filter_array` если он сразу формируется, то навряд-ли вы узнаете какая ячейка создалась первой, а какая последней. Если заполняется, например, с помощью `array_push`, то последний элемент всегда добавился последним, исходя из этого можно уже можно сделать то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($catalog_filter_array['category'])) {
    $category_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['category'], 'girls');
    $term = $category_term;

} else if(isset($catalog_filter_array['service'])) {
    $service_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['service'], 'services');

    $term = $service_term;
} else if(isset($catalog_filter_array['city'])) {
    $city_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['city'], 'city');

    $term = $city_term;
}
```

Comment: они могуть быть 3 сразу на странице. Важно что бы в переменной был последний. А так сработает на первом совпадении

Comment: @Vlad467 тогда я не совсем понял суть "последний", по какому параметру он определяется? у нас ведь нету времени создания данного ключа? как мы можем узнать последний?

Answer (score 0):

Ну например, добавить некий переключатель, и проверять, не был ли он активирован:

```
$triger = false;

if (isset($catalog_filter_array['category'])) {
    $category_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['category'], 'girls');
    $term = $category_term;
    $triger = true;
}

if (! $triger && isset($catalog_filter_array['service'])) {
    $service_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['service'], 'services');
    $term = $service_term;
    $triger = true;
}

if (! $triger && isset($catalog_filter_array['city'])) {
    $city_term = get_term_by('slug', $catalog_filter_array['city'], 'city');
    $term = $city_term;
}
```